# Error 424: Object Required Using Vlookup in a Loop

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, vlookup

Basically what I am trying to do here is have my macro build out a URL which will be scraped and used to populate information. I intend for the URL to be unique according to specific securities and data fields specified.

I am receiving an error in my j loop with using the Datatype string within a vlookup. I intend for it to return a value which will be used to populate my URL.

```
Dim Last1 As Integer: Last1 = W.Range("A1000").End(xlUp).Row
Dim Last2 As Integer: Last2 = W.Range("XFD1").End(xlToLeft).Column
Dim IE As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
Dim html As HTMLDocument
If Last = 1 Then Exit Sub
Dim Symbols As String
Dim DataType As String
Dim URLParameters As String
Dim i, j As Integer


    For i = 2 To Last1
        Symbols = Symbols & Worksheets("Stock Prices").Range("A" & i).Value & "+"
    Next i

    Symbols = Left(Symbols, Len(Symbols) - 1)

    Debug.Print Symbols

    For j = 2 To Last2

        DataType = DataType & Worksheets("Stock Prices").Cells(1, j).Value

        URLParameters = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(DataType, Worksheets("URL Info").Range("URL_DataInfo"), 2).Value

    Next j
    Debug.Print DataType
    Debug.Print URLParameters

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

'Tells IE where to pull
IE.navigate "https://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes?s=" & Symbols & "&f=" & URLParameters
IE.Visible = True

'Wait until IE is done loading page
Do While IE.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
Application.StatusBar = "Pulling data..."
DoEvents
Loop
'show text of HTML document returned
Set html = IE.document
'MsgBox html.DocumentElement.innerHTML
'close down IE and reset status bar
Set IE = Nothing
Application.StatusBar = ""

'Remove HTML tags
Dim info As String
info = cook_tags(CStr(html.DocumentElement.innerHTML))

'Split the results into cells
Call split_data(info)

End Sub
```

Comment: Why do you keep **appending** information to `DataType`?  It **may** be what you need to do, but it sure looks strange, and would certainly explain why you are getting errors (after the code fixes mentioned in the current answers) from `VLookup` not matching the data passed to it.

Comment: I'm trying create a loop which uses a vlookup from what is picked up in the DataType String and matches it in the URLParameters to flesh out a URL. Thoughts?

Comment: So if the first lookup is for something like "ABC", then the next lookup will be for "ABCXYZ", and the next lookup will be for "ABCXYZGHJ", etc.  Is that what you are after?  Or are you after lookups for "ABC", then for "XYZ", then for "GHJ"?

Comment: @Jeeped solved my question. I was looking to string together a URL bit on the basis of what DataType looped through and matched to the appropriate URL additive. For instance, if there were 10 pieces it would all string together ABCDEFGHIJ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current code asks the [VLOOKUP function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/vlookup-function-adceda66-30de-4f26-923b-7257939faa65) for an apprimate match. The data **must** be sorted in an ascending order for this to even remotely work.

Use a variant-type to accept the returned value and get rid of the [WorksheetFunction object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834434.aspx). If you use the [Excel Application object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194565.aspx) alone, you can return errors to a variant.

You are not returning a [Range.Value property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195193.aspx), simply a VLOOKUP's returned value.

```
Dim URLParameters As variant
URLParameters = Application.VLookup(DataType, Worksheets("URL Info").Range("URL_DataInfo"), 2, FALSE)
if IsError(URLParameters) Then
    'no value found
else
    'value found and put in URLParameters
end if
```

Comment: I will go through the process of adding If IsError qualifiers, but for right now I am simply trying to get the function to return a value, which it is failing to do accurately. I changed the nature of my vlookup to an exact match. When I shift URLParameters to a variant I am getting Error 2042 and is conflicting with my IE.Navigate function later on. I would prefer to keep it as a String if possible.

Comment: @Simple - your problem with using a Variant when you get to the IE.Navigate function is probably because your VLookup didn't match anything (see my comment to the question itself for **why** it is probably not matching) and is thus returning an error condition.  By including the suggested `IsError`, the code could detect the "no match" conditions and perform some graceful error handling, rather than failing further down in the code.

Comment: OK. I see what you're saying. I included the following Code:  

If IsError(DataType) Then
    'no value found
        Else
    'value found and put in URLParameters
        End If

I am still getting an error stating that an object is required. Im not just looking for a solution here, I want to understand what is actually going wrong with the logic... What object is required to execute: 

URLParameters = URLParameters & Application.VLookup(DataType, Worksheets("URL Info").Range("URL_DataInfo"), 2).Value

that hasn't been included in previous lines of code?

Answer (score 0):

The `VLOOKUP` formula returns the *value* from the matching cell. Try

```
URLParameters = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(DataType, Worksheets("URL Info").Range("URL_DataInfo"), 2)
```

In stead of this (note the `.Value` at the end of the Function call, which is incorrect):

```
URLParameters = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(DataType, Worksheets("URL Info").Range("URL_DataInfo"), 2).Value
```

You may receive further errors if the return data type of the `Vlookup` function is not string (i.e., especially if it is an Error type). In that case, it may be preferable to test for errors, and avoid the `WorksheetFunction` class for this:

```
With Worksheets("URL Parameters")
    If Not IsError(Application.VLookup(DataType, .Range("URL_DataInfo"), 2)) Then
        URLParameters = Application.VLookup(DataType, .Range("URL_DataInfo"), 2)
    Else

        '## Here, you'll need some error handling or exit sub early, etc.

    End If
End With
```

Comment: OK. Removing the .value got rid of the object required error, but isnt returning the appropriate information. Instead of returning the appropriate content in the "URL_DataInfo" named range it is only returning the character "i" (which is no where in the named range)  over and over equivalent to the columns rolled by the j loop.

Comment: @DavidZemens - Wouldn't it be more appropriate to add your own answer?  This is now roughly 20% of the original answer's content.

Comment: @comintern maybe, but I was mainly just improving the existing answer didn't feel like I needed to add my own